# Git signing tags and log

Tags: git, git-tag

I have have several signed tags on my repository.
When I use:

```
$git show tag_name
```

the pgp signature appears, between all information on the tag.

However if I use:

```
 git log --pretty="format:%H %G?"
```

the option %G? displays always N, as if none of the tags had been signed.
Why does this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you see the tag when you do `git log --pretty="format:%H %G?" tag_name`? Signed tags are not ancestors of commits, but children.

Comment: Do you mean tag_name in the information displayed? No, i can't.    If I do ´git log --pretty="format:%H %G?" tag_name´ i get the list of commits until the tagged one.

Comment: `git log` lists commits, not tags. `%G` displays information about signed _commits_ but you're expecting it to say something about the signed _tags_. Git seems to work as expected here.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to git and i'm a bit confused about tags and commits.Is much different signing a tag or a commit?